# Rspec Capybara - Login(user) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hello i have a Rspec/Capybara test im trying to make.

Im a logged in user that as admin user should be the only user to add Sizes to my app.

I just can't get the test to Login the user. Can anyone see why?

Please look at the sessions controller below. I do have a log_in method.

Error is

```
Failures:

  1) adding size allow a admin user to add a size
     Failure/Error: log_in(admin)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `log_in' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AddingSize:0x007f8e4fa828e0>
     # ./spec/features/sizes_features.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Test

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do 

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.build :size01 }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true) }

    scenario "allow a admin user to add a size" do
        log_in(admin)
        size = create(:size01)
        visit new_size_path
        fill_in 'Title', with: "example"
        click_button 'Create Size'
        expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("example")
    end

    scenario "user can't add size" do
        log_in(user)
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("Rescricted Web Page")
    end

    scenario "vistor can't add size" do
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

end
```

FactoryGirl

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user, :class => User do
        username "example" 
        email "example@example.com" 
        admin "false" 
        password_digest "<%= User.digest('password') %>"
      activated "true"
      activated_at "<%= Time.zone.now %>"
  end

end
```

Sessions controller.

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is why it's not working:

> Access to session and request is not possible from the test, Access to
>   response is limited. Some drivers allow access to response headers and
>   HTTP status code, but this kind of functionality is not provided by
>   some drivers, such as Selenium.

[source: Capybara documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md)

You have two options:

1. If you're using Devise for authentication, Devise provides authentication helpers you should use.
2. Otherwise, here's how I would approach your situation:

   Instead of trying to directly manipulate the session, create a shared context or a helper that logs in the user by interacting with the login form in the same way a user browsing your site would.

   Here is one approach:

   **spec/support/when_authenticated.rb**

   ```
   RSpec.shared_context 'When authenticated' do
     background do
       authenticate
     end

     def authenticate
       visit '/sessions/new'
       within('form#session') do
         fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@example.com'
         fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
       end
       click_button 'Sign in'
     end
   end
   ```

   Then, in your feature spec:

   ```
   RSpec.feature 'User does something' do
     include_context 'When authenticated'

     # examples
   end
   ```

   This has the effect of running the authentication procedure before each example in your spec.

Comment: Thanks Madcow. Good answer. I did what you said. I ran the test and i get this error? I tried to fix it. Do you have any clues?  /Users/joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:348:in `find_and_eval_shared': Could not find shared context "When authenticated" (ArgumentError)

Comment: Make sure you have something like this in your `spec_helper.rb`: `Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}`